# Typescript partial interface overloading is choosing wrong overload

Tags: typescript

When I am trying to define an overload my function with a Partial interface overloading, typescript is picking the wrong overload

```js
interface Args {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
}
interface Result {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
}

function myFunction(arg: Args): Result;
function myFunction(arg: Partial<Args>): Partial<Result> {
  return arg;
}

// Argument of type '{ _id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Args'.
// Property 'name' is missing in type '{ _id: string; }' but required in type 'Args'
myFunction({ _id: 'aa' });
```

Trying to use `myFunction({ _id: 'aa' } as Partial<Args>);` doesn't help

How could I make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last signature is the implementation signature and is not part of the publicly accessible signatures. So your function really on has one accessible signature `function myFunction(arg: Args): Result;` hence the error.

```
function myFunction(arg: Args): Result;
function myFunction(arg: Partial<Args>): Partial<Result>
function myFunction(arg: Partial<Args>): Partial<Result> {
  return arg;
}

myFunction({ _id: 'aa' });// ok now
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYGdkG8BQyyA+sACYBcyWYUoGA3IciHALYRU10iP4C++UJFiIUAJQhYArgBsweZqUrVa9JkVYcua3k0H4Y0kAjDAA9iGRsAngDFjpiyAAUcTFXTYAlFUkz5JiMTM0tre0dQ13cMKgAFdzM4WQAeLywAPl9kBKgk1P85MAzDSOdwhxDnNw8cxOBktMxM7Nz8lML5DMUiKAgwaSgrGP18fFtKp0sXXBJyKgByODgF5H5vBiA)

Comment: I will add that the overloads order matter as typescript will take the first that works, so in this case you should always put the Partial one last, else the other will never be taken